# When I pass an argument to a bound function, it references the second parameter instead. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, call, bind

```js
let info = {
  fname: "John",
  lname: "Smith"
}

const print = function(city, country) {
  console.log(
    `I am ${this.fname} ${this.lname}. Living in ${city}, ${country}`)
}

const bound = print.bind(info, "California")

bound('USA')

//output: I am John Smith. Living in California, USA
```

The `bind()` method returns a new function with `this` referencing the `bind()` first argument.

My question is, if I pass the "USA" argument to the bound function, it references the "`country`" parameter and not the "`city`".  Why is that? I don't understand.

Comment: You bound `"California"` to the first parameter.

Comment: Does that mean `country` will automatically become the first parameter in the bound function?

Comment: The first argument of [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is bound to `this`, the remaining arguments are bound to the first arguments of the referred function. Read the [documentation of `Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). The `bound()` function has `this` and `city` bound to `info` and `'California'`, only the `country` argument can be passed to it.

Comment: Yes, that's how `bind()` works. Arguments 2-n of `bind()` become arguments 1-(n-1) of the bound function. Arguments that you pass to the bound function go after the ones in `.bind()`.

Comment: What did you think `California` was, a default value? No, that's not how it works.